# Android Studio equivalent of Command + O to view local class members

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the Android Studio version of <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse that will show all of the LOCAL class members? I see that it can do the same thing in Android Studio, but it brings up all of the methods in every project. I only want to bring up the methods in the class file that I am currently in.

In Android Studio, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> looks good but it brings up all methods in other projects not local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found it on the Mac:

<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

I also found that <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> will give you a list pane with the local class members.

The same menu can be navigated to by going to: *View ► Tool Windows ► Structure*

[image]